# Getting Custom List columns with JSLink Context

Tags: custom-list, jslink

I have a custom list in SharePoint 2013 and I'm using a javascript file to style it utilising the JSLink capabilities to reduce server load etc.  The problem I'm having is that my custom list as a few different custom fields in it that I need to display and my question is how do I show those fields?

```
(function () {
    var itemCtx = {};
itemCtx.Templates = {};

itemCtx.Templates.Header = "<div><h1>Test Head</h1></div><table>";
itemCtx.Templates.Item = ItemOverrideFun;
itemCtx.Templates.Footer = "</table>";

itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1;
// 100 is Custom List
itemCtx.ListTemplateType = 100;

SPClientTemplates.TemplateManager.RegisterTemplateOverrides(itemCtx);

})();

function ItemOverrideFun(ctx) {

    var Title = ctx.CurrentItem.Title;
     var Body = ctx.CurrentItem.Body;
       var ID = ctx.CurrentItem.ID;


    return  "<p>" + Title + "</p>" +
            "<p>" + Body + "</p>" +
            "<p>" + ID + "</p>" +
            "<a href='/Lists/Company%20Announcements/DispForm.aspx?ID=’+ _announcementID +’> Read More</a></td></tr>" ;
            }
```

My code works however the CurrentItem.Body renders as "undefined" and I'd like it to be my field called "BodyText".

Does anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the simplest way the field to be accessible in rendering template, just to include this field in a List View.

Go to Edit View page and select the column as shown on figure below
[image]

Then you could access this field:

```
var assignedTo = ctx.CurrentItem.AssignedTo;
```

Comment: I know how to do that but this is a custom column called "BodyText" and I want to display that. Simply typing 

    ctx.CurrentItem.BodyText

It comes back as undefined.

Comment: This occurs since your custom column is not included in a list view. Please make sure that the view where custom rendering is applied contains this field.

Comment: Thanks for that, the columns are in the view I've made sure, what I've noticed is that the column "BodyText" is rich text if that makes difference.  I made another column for the username of the person who wrote the news article and I can't display that either despite it being shown in the view.  They just come back as undefined.  It's so frustrating am I missing something?

Comment: Try to to comment the line: itemCtx.BaseViewID = 1; since you are customizing the current view.  I hope it will do the trick

Comment: Great, glad it works finally! ;)